# what url should the client call to a server in the same domain

Tags: javascript, java, http, angular

I have a server and a client on the same domain.

Client:
http://localhost:8080/ST/html/pages/gasolina/

```
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        this.cachedConfigs = response.json() as CountryConfig[];
        return action(this.cachedConfigs);
      });
```

Server:
http://localhost:8080/ST/Gas/Config

If i want to the client to call the server,

What url should I call?

If I call this url:

`'/ST/Gas/Config'`

I get `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused <= Connection refused` error

If I call this url:

`'http://locahost:8080/ST/Gas/Config'`

I get

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://locahost:8080/ST/Gas/Config. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0):

Use your private ip to call the server

```
http://192.168.1.100:8080/Gas/Config
```

or maybe your web browser is treating the url as a website use

```
localhost:8080/Gas/Config
```